# enable button only if older than 90 days

Tags: php, sql, button

Good Day

I have a delete button which deletes entries on my database, problem is I want to disable the button and only enable it if it is older than 90 days.

I used this code and it's working but if it's not older than 90 days it still replies "successfully deleted" although it was not actually deleted and that is why I thought it would be easier to disable the delete button and only enable it if the entry is older than 90 days

please assist

Thanking you

```
$sql="DELETE FROM client_post WHERE id = '$id' AND date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);        


if($result){
         echo('Entry '.$id.' successfully deleted <br>');
} else{
         echo('<br>Failed to delete');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change if statement to:

```
  if($result && mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
```

Problem with your code is that you are checking if the $result is true, while $result is just an identifier of mysql_query() results. You should check also how much rows where affected by the query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the rest of the code?

I guess you want to make a check if there are any entries older than 90 days, the button is enabled.

Do you have some kind of list where all entries are shown, and on each entry there is a delete button?

To answer your actual question, you'll need to supply us with more code.

Answer (score 0):

As michal said you can use the affected rows to actually check if a row got deleted with:

```
if($result && mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
```

If you still want to disable the button tho you can use

```
SELECT 
     IF( DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE( ), date ) > 90, 1, 0 ) 
FROM 
     client_post
WHERE
     id = $id
```

This will return true or false depending on the entry age. Depending on that you can show the button or not.

Also, take a look at `PDO` much better. MySQL api is deprecated.